# Photoshop CEP panel remote hosting?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, photoshop, extendscript, complex-event-processing

Hi I am new to Adobe CEP panels, so please forgive me if this is a frequently asked question

I have built my first CEP panel and it is working well, however, in order to make this more useful to others within the company, it would make sense if I were able to host it on one of the company's webservers then anyone in the company could access it.  Also, any updates to the html/js/jsx would then only need to be made in one place.  I've spent quite some time googling but I've not found any examples.

I would be grateful for any thoughts or suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

**Technically NO!!!!**

Well as you've mentioned that you've already made your first CEP panel and it's also working fine, I can assume you've gone through the method of loading test panels via **PlayerDebugMode 1**.

So here is the catch. Photoshop only recognises 2 type of extensions called Signed and Unsigned. So when you create a new panel in your local appdata/library - CEP - extensions folder, You creates a unsigned panel and photoshop considers that as test/development panel. When you finish your panel and then make it distributable by either making installable package like .exe or .dmg or .zxp, It gets signed and photoshop considers them as signed plugins and will install it automatically on their legit path.

> if I were able to host it on one of the company's webservers then anyone in the company could access it.

The only way I could manage was sharing latest .zxp to my work server where my other designer mates copied and installed them into their system. That's what you can do if you really want to share but you can't assign some global path to extensions because photoshop won't allow you to do it. Regards!

Comment: What prevents you or OP to have a iframe with code that's loaded from somewhere outside of PS folder? There're a lot of panels that do that. And this has nothing to do with the way the panel is distributed.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy you saying to make an iframe and put href to server path right? but still it'll only load the html in the plugin but at least we need to install plugin on every separate computers. I think above person asking to access plugin from server without installing them at all, which currently seems impossible for me.

Comment: Ah, maybe, that requires some clarification. On a separate note, if the server is mapped as a drive, one can make a symbolic link to that remote folder.

Comment: I've spoken with our Adobe client liaison and it looks like they are pushing Adobe as a service (initially this will just be photoshop) - it's in invite beta atm.  The idea will be that you generate a config file and push it to the cloud for processing the output can then be returned in any format and can be pushed to any location in the world. That's the future vision so I expect I shall join the Beta and see where it takes us. - The final vision will be a seamless API  covering the entire CC product range, lots of AI and CL baked in. - Exciting?

Comment: Adobe always gets something boiling in their minds :)